# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.google.android.gms.wallet.ocr.CardRecognitionShimProxyActivity

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

After I release my app in google play I noticed one **crash** issue in **Google play developer console / Pre-launch report on mobile Pixel 5.**

App is built using **Flutter framework**.

Kindly guid me to fix this.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: [com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$ChimeraService-Executor] idle
Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2823
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.google.android.gms.wallet.ocr.CardRecognitionShimProxyActivity does not exist in com.google.android.gms
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2377)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:6793)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2714)
    at m.bfw.j(:com.google.android.gms.policy_payments@213380802@213380802065.395552306.395552306:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.wallet.common.ModuleInitializer.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_payments@213380802@213380802065.395552306.395552306:2)
    at m.apa.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms.policy_payments@213380802@213380802065.395552306.395552306:6)
    at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@213017046@21.30.17 (150400-395706864):2)
    at sfq.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@213017046@21.30.17 (150400-395706864):4)
    at eka.run(:com.google.android.gms@213017046@21.30.17 (150400-395706864):5)
    at ejz.run(:com.google.android.gms@213017046@21.30.17 (150400-395706864):11)
    at bwof.run(:com.google.android.gms@213017046@21.30.17 (150400-395706864):2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21135)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setComponentEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:20980)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3207)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4312)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
```

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be app specific nor flutter specific. I am suddenly seeing it in the Pre-launch report on Pixel 5, for one of my apps. The app doesn't use flutter.

Comment: Same thing here. I saw it with Pixel 5 pre-launch report.

Answer (score 0):

I'd had a similar problem, apparently the device is looking for a method on "com.google.android.gms.wallet". It seems to be a bug on one of the google test devices. A workaround could be include the dependency, even if your app don't use it.
To do it, include on your gradle app file:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:*version*'`

The actual version is: 18.1.3.

Comment: Why should I include it if my app does not use it? if it's a bug from Google test devices, then I should expect my app won't crash on real devices. Correct?

Comment: Yep... Assuming that you have already tested it with your device/emulator and nothing shows up.

Comment: the workaround was a option to get rid of the warning, because that was the question... but i don't recommend it either, your app would carry a lot of unnecessary things.

Comment: I will be monitoring real devices. Hopefully this error won’t occur . Thanks!